# What's the difference between property instantiation methods esp. with respect to a service base class?

Tags: angular

What's the difference between instantiating a property on a component or service like

```
@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
  _svc = new Service1();
```

and

```
constructor(private _svc: Service1)
```

and

```
constructor(){
  _svc = new Service1();
```

and

```
constructor(_svc1: Service1){
  _svc = _svc1;
```

?

For the most part, I'm using method 2, but all of them seemed to have the same result until I tried to create a base class for API services. By calling super() in the child service constructors I found I could use method 1 for a service of just functions, method 3 for some other static classes, and couldn't find a working way to instantiate angular's Http in the base class at all. I'm also concerned about performance and whether the "new" keyword will reuse a singleton from the module providers or create a new one.

Can someone please clarify what the difference between the methods is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between service and component. 
You can use all of them on both.

If you have a modifier like `private`, `protected`, or `public` on a constructor parameter an class level field is implicitly created and the value assigned.

```
class Service2 {
  constructor(private _svc: Service1) {}

  foo() {
    console.log(this._svc); // ok
  }
}
```

is similar to

```
class Service2 {
  _svc: Service1;

  constructor(_svc: Service1) {
    this._svc = _svc;
  }

  foo() {
    console.log(this._svc); // ok
  }
}
```

Your other variants don't create a class level field. `_svc` will only be available within the constructor body.

In the examples above Angular calls `new Service1()` for you.
When you call it yourself, like

```
class Service2 {
  constructor(){
    _svc = new Service1();
  }
}
```

then you also need to pass dependencies (constructor parameters of `Service1`) to `new Service1(dep1, dep2)`.
If you have such dependencies and let Angular create the instance, it will look up dependencies in it's registered providers and pass them along as well.

When Angular creates the instance for you, it will also ensure only a single instance will be created per registered provider.
So if you only provide `Service1` in `@NgModule(...)` of `AppModule` there will ever only be a single instance.
If you create an instance yourself using `new Service1()`, Angular doesn't know about that and there will be more than one instance.

Comment: Thanks for a great response! Seems like using "extends" and super() doesn't have a ton of value since I would have to pass all the dependencies into super() anyway, but calling constructor(private _svc: Service1) {} allows me to use this._svc.service1Param in Service2 and that's about the best I can do in search of DRY code?

Comment: If you can share code, then you can extend, but for constructor parameters alone it is often not useful. If you always have the same constructor parameters as the base class, you can just omit the constructor in the inherited class, then Angular DI uses the constructor of the base class.